# Checking an input in Java

Tags: java, string, input, compare

First let me start off by saying I'm new to Java and I'm not a professional programmer but I have written several macros in VBA.

I'm trying to help my son with his high school Java assignment.  In the assignment there is a point where the user has a Y or N input.  I can't figure out why this code doesn't work.

```
            // Wait for user to press Y or N
        do{
            playAgain = input.next();
        } while (!playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || (!playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

It works if I only check for one condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic says to continue looping so long as the input does not equal `n/N` *or* `y/Y`.  This will always be true for both yes and no inputs, and in fact *all* inputs.  If no is entered, the first condition would fail, but the second would be true, and vice-versa for yes.

To remedy this, you should `&&` together the two conditions:

```
 do {
     playAgain = input.next();
} while (!playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("n") && (!playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

|| means OR. So, A || B is true if A is true or B is true. Any Or condition works like this: If first part if true, then second condition is not evaluated. If first is false, then second is evaluated. If either is true, then the result is true.

In your do while loop: !playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("n") will be true if "y" is equal to your input and vice versa. Either way any one of the condition will always be true in the while loop condition, so the loop will go forever. The solution is mentioned in the answer given above. (use && instead of ||)